# add params to the 'output-file' parameter

Tags: r, quarto

I am looking for an way to use `params` in the `output-file` for rendering parameterized reports, ie. something along these lines.

````
---
format: 
  html:
     output-file: `r paste0('Report_',params$example)`
     output-ext: html
params:
  example: "Tester"
---


```{r}
params$example
```
````

Instead of (the currently working solution) `quarto_render` based on [this blog post](https://meghan.rbind.io/blog/quarto-pdfs/):

```
runhtmls <- function(example) {
  quarto::quarto_render(
    "test.qmd",
    output_format = "html",
    execute_params = list(example = example),
    output_file = glue::glue("{example}.html")
  )
}

purrr::map(c("example1"), 
           runhtmls)
```